# Mongoose countDocuments() returning query

Tags: mongoose

I am trying to count the number of Loans a specific user has from an API call. The Loans schema has a user field with the id of the related user. To count the loans:

```
router.get('/loans/count:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {   
      const count = Loans.countDocuments({ user: req.params.id });
      console.log(count);
      res.json({ count: count });
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```

I just need the result to be a number with the count of the number of documents. How can I do that?

This is the error:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 500 at createError (createError.js:16) at settle (settle.js:17) at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:61)

Comment: this worked thank you. Count is deprecated so i replaced it with countDocuments and still worked. Now trying to see how i handle the return when calling it!

Comment: Glad I could help, please upvote and accept the answer. It will help your reputation as well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return the response object like so:

```
router.get('/loans/count:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {   
      const count = Loans.countDocuments({ user: req.params.id });
      console.log(count);
      res.status(200).send({count: count});
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server Error');
  }
});
```